# Reading the nested object in the nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

My problem is reading properties of nested object, which is inside other nested object.

**GraphQL**

```
type Mapping {
    id: ID!
    partnerSegmentId: ID!
    ctSegmentId: CtSegment!
}

type PartnerSegment {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    platformId: Int!
    partner: Partner!
}

type Partner {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}
```

Once I try to query it like:

```
{
  allMappings {
    partnerSegmentId {
      id
      name
      partner {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I recieve:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMappings": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Partner.name.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 8,
          "column": 9
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "allMappings",
        0,
        "partnerSegmentId",
        "partner",
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Mapping schema**

```
const mappingSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        partnerSegmentId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'PartnerSegment',
            required: [true, 'Mapping must have partner segment id.']
        },

        ctSegmentId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'CtSegment',
            required: [true, 'Mapping must have CT segment id.']
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

I tried to read separately Partner, PartnerSegment and Mapping models. All works fine. Any idea where i should search source of the problem? I've checked mongodb docs and ids looks okay. I suppose it's fault of my model.

If you would like to take a closer look it's [project repo](https://github.com/danzawadzki/express-graphql-api).

Comment: Did you checked which data are returned for `PartnerSegment .Name`? It looks like that `Name` is `null`.

Comment: @kat1330 I keep object id in the database. I checked directly in the database if everything is okay and I do not see an mistake there. In addition, I made a simple select by this id and everything works. The problem shows up, once it's nested inside other object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Garbage Id in the return value was caused by not working populate in the nested entity. The way I managed to solve the problem:

```
const allMappings = () =>
    Mapping.find({})
        .populate('user')
        .populate('ctSegment')
        .populate({
            path: 'partnerSegment',
            populate: {
                path: 'partner'
            }
        })
        .exec();
```